# Stored procedure for product search with dynamic filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Below stored procedure implemented for filtering and sorting operation.But number of table column increases below query becomes complex to read/maintain. This is good for small tables.

I want to modify the below one by using dynamic sql query. I will pass the parameter from front-end to here.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspProductWithPagingSortingFiltering]
(
-- Optional Filters for Dynamic Search
@ProductID INT = NULL,
@Name NAME = NULL,
@ProductNumber NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
@Color NVARCHAR(15) = NULL,
@StandardCost MONEY = NULL,
@ListPrice MONEY = NULL,
@Size NVARCHAR(5) = NULL,
@Weight DECIMAL = NULL,
@ProductCategoryID INT = NULL,
@ProductModelID INT = NULL,
@SellStartDate DATETIME = NULL,
@SellEndDate DATETIME = NULL,
@DiscontinuedDate DATETIME = NULL,
@ThumbNailPhoto VARBINARY = NULL,
@ThumbnailPhotoFileName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@rowguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
@ModifiedDate DATETIME = NULL,
-- Pagination Parameters
@PageNo INT = 1,
@PageSize INT = 25,
-- Sorting Parameters
@SortColumn NVARCHAR(20),
@SortOrder NVARCHAR(4) = 'ASC'
)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declaring Local Variables corresponding to parameters for modification
DECLARE
@lProductID INT,
@lName NAME,
@lProductNumber NVARCHAR(25),
@lColor NVARCHAR(15),
@lStandardCost MONEY,
@lListPrice MONEY,
@lSize NVARCHAR(5),
@lWeight DECIMAL,
@lProductCategoryID INT,
@lProductModelID INT,
@lSellStartDate DATETIME,
@lSellEndDate DATETIME,
@lDiscontinuedDate DATETIME,
@lThumbNailPhoto VARBINARY,
@lThumbnailPhotoFileName NVARCHAR(50),
@lrowguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@lModifiedDate DATETIME,

@lPageNbr INT,
@lPageSize INT,
@lSortCol NVARCHAR(20),
@lFirstRec INT,
@lLastRec INT,
@lTotalRows INT,
@TotalCount INT

-- Setting Local Variables
SET @lProductID = @ProductID
SET @lName = @Name
SET @lProductNumber = @ProductNumber
SET @lColor = @Color
SET @lStandardCost = @StandardCost
SET @lListPrice = @ListPrice
SET @lSize = @Size
SET @lWeight = @Weight
SET @lProductCategoryID = @ProductCategoryID
SET @lProductModelID = @ProductModelID
SET @lSellStartDate = @SellStartDate
SET @lSellEndDate = @SellEndDate
SET @lDiscontinuedDate = @DiscontinuedDate
SET @lThumbNailPhoto = @ThumbNailPhoto
SET @lThumbnailPhotoFileName = @ThumbnailPhotoFileName
SET @lrowguid = @rowguid
SET @lModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate

SET @lPageNbr = @PageNo
SET @lPageSize = @PageSize
SET @lSortCol = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SortColumn))

SET @lFirstRec = ( @lPageNbr - 1 ) * @lPageSize
SET @lLastRec = ( @lPageNbr * @lPageSize + 1 )
SET @lTotalRows = @lFirstRec - @lLastRec + 1

; WITH ResultsCTE
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductID' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ProductID] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductID' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ProductID] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Name' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [Name] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Name' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [Name] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductNumber' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ProductNumber] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductNumber' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ProductNumber] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Color' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [Color] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Color' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [Color] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'StandardCost' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [StandardCost] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'StandardCost' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [StandardCost] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ListPrice' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ListPrice] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ListPrice' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ListPrice] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Size' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [Size] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Size' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [Size] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Weight' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [Weight] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Weight' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [Weight] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductCategoryID' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ProductCategoryID] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductCategoryID' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ProductCategoryID] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductModelID' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ProductModelID] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductModelID' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ProductModelID] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellStartDate' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [SellStartDate] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellStartDate' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [SellStartDate] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellEndDate' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [SellEndDate] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellEndDate' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [SellEndDate] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'DiscontinuedDate' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [DiscontinuedDate] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'DiscontinuedDate' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [DiscontinuedDate] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbNailPhoto' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ThumbNailPhoto] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbNailPhoto' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ThumbNailPhoto] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbnailPhotoFileName' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbnailPhotoFileName' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'rowguid' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [rowguid] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'rowguid' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [rowguid] END DESC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ModifiedDate' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [ModifiedDate] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ModifiedDate' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [ModifiedDate] END DESC
) AS ROWNUM,
Count(*) over () AS TotalCount,
[ProductID],
[Name],
[ProductNumber],
[Color],
[StandardCost],
[ListPrice],
[Size],
[Weight],
[ProductCategoryID],
[ProductModelID],
[SellStartDate],
[SellEndDate],
[DiscontinuedDate],
[ThumbNailPhoto],
[ThumbnailPhotoFileName],
[rowguid],
[ModifiedDate]
FROM SalesLT.Product
WHERE
(@lProductID IS NULL OR [ProductID] = @lProductID)
AND
(@lName IS NULL OR [Name] like '%' + @lName + '%')
AND
(@lProductNumber IS NULL OR [ProductNumber] like '%' + @lProductNumber + '%')
AND
(@lColor IS NULL OR [Color] like '%' + @lColor + '%')
AND
(@lStandardCost IS NULL OR [StandardCost] = @lStandardCost)
AND
(@lListPrice IS NULL OR [ListPrice] = @lListPrice)
AND
(@lSize IS NULL OR [Size] like '%' + @lSize + '%')
AND
(@lWeight IS NULL OR [Weight] = @lWeight)
AND
(@lProductCategoryID IS NULL OR [ProductCategoryID] = @lProductCategoryID)
AND
(@lProductModelID IS NULL OR [ProductModelID] = @lProductModelID)
AND
(@lSellStartDate IS NULL OR [SellStartDate] = @lSellStartDate)
AND
(@lSellEndDate IS NULL OR [SellEndDate] = @lSellEndDate)
AND
(@lDiscontinuedDate IS NULL OR [DiscontinuedDate] = @lDiscontinuedDate)
AND
(@lThumbNailPhoto IS NULL OR [ThumbNailPhoto] = @lThumbNailPhoto)
AND
(@lThumbnailPhotoFileName IS NULL OR [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] like '%' + @lThumbnailPhotoFileName + '%')
AND
(@lrowguid IS NULL OR [rowguid] = @lrowguid)
AND
(@lModifiedDate IS NULL OR [ModifiedDate] = @lModifiedDate)
)

SELECT * INTO #Results FROM ResultsCTE

SELECT @TotalCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM SalesLT.Product)

SELECT
[ProductID],
[Name],
[ProductNumber],
[Color],
[StandardCost],
[ListPrice],
[Size],
[Weight],
[ProductCategoryID],
[ProductModelID],
[SellStartDate],
[SellEndDate],
[DiscontinuedDate],
[ThumbNailPhoto],
[ThumbnailPhotoFileName],
[rowguid],
[ModifiedDate]
FROM #Results AS Results
WHERE ROWNUM > @lFirstRec AND ROWNUM < @lLastRec
ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC

RETURN @TotalCount

END
GO
```

How can i modify the above stored procedure in a better manner when number of column increases  by using dynamic sql queries?

Answer (score 1):

**Dynamic Sorting**

You could reduce half of the `CASE` statements by removing the explict `ASC/DESC` sorting.

For example, the `CASE` statements would turn into:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductID') THEN [ProductID] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Name') THEN [Name] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductNumber') THEN [ProductNumber] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Color') THEN [Color] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'StandardCost') THEN [StandardCost] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ListPrice') THEN [ListPrice] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Size') THEN [Size] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Weight') THEN [Weight] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductCategoryID') THEN [ProductCategoryID] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductModelID') THEN [ProductModelID] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellStartDate') THEN [SellStartDate] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellEndDate') THEN [SellEndDate] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'DiscontinuedDate') THEN [DiscontinuedDate] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbNailPhoto') THEN [ThumbNailPhoto] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbnailPhotoFileName') THEN [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'rowguid') THEN [rowguid] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ModifiedDate') THEN [ModifiedDate] END
) AS ROWNUM
```

Obviously this doesn't provide a sort direction. So to do this, we just include a new variable that acts as a multiple dependent upon your `@SortOrder` variable.

```
DECLARE @SortMultiplier INT = CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'ASC' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
```

Finally, when you actually perform the `ORDER BY`. We can just multiply the value returned by ROW_NUMBER and the multiplier:

```
ORDER BY ROWNUM * @SortMultiplier
```

Therefore, if it's `ASC` order, the row number won't change. However, if its `DESC` order, the numbers will be inverted to there negative counterparts. Essentially providing you with a descending order.

The final solution looking as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspProductWithPagingSortingFiltering]
(
-- Optional Filters for Dynamic Search
@ProductID INT = NULL,
@Name NAME = NULL,
@ProductNumber NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
@Color NVARCHAR(15) = NULL,
@StandardCost MONEY = NULL,
@ListPrice MONEY = NULL,
@Size NVARCHAR(5) = NULL,
@Weight DECIMAL = NULL,
@ProductCategoryID INT = NULL,
@ProductModelID INT = NULL,
@SellStartDate DATETIME = NULL,
@SellEndDate DATETIME = NULL,
@DiscontinuedDate DATETIME = NULL,
@ThumbNailPhoto VARBINARY = NULL,
@ThumbnailPhotoFileName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@rowguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
@ModifiedDate DATETIME = NULL,
-- Pagination Parameters
@PageNo INT = 1,
@PageSize INT = 25,
-- Sorting Parameters
@SortColumn NVARCHAR(20),
@SortOrder NVARCHAR(4) = 'ASC'
)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declaring Local Variables corresponding to parameters for modification
DECLARE
@lProductID INT,
@lName NAME,
@lProductNumber NVARCHAR(25),
@lColor NVARCHAR(15),
@lStandardCost MONEY,
@lListPrice MONEY,
@lSize NVARCHAR(5),
@lWeight DECIMAL,
@lProductCategoryID INT,
@lProductModelID INT,
@lSellStartDate DATETIME,
@lSellEndDate DATETIME,
@lDiscontinuedDate DATETIME,
@lThumbNailPhoto VARBINARY,
@lThumbnailPhotoFileName NVARCHAR(50),
@lrowguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@lModifiedDate DATETIME,

@lPageNbr INT,
@lPageSize INT,
@lSortCol NVARCHAR(20),
@lFirstRec INT,
@lLastRec INT,
@lTotalRows INT,
@TotalCount INT,
@SortMultiplier INT

-- Setting Local Variables
SET @lProductID = @ProductID
SET @lName = @Name
SET @lProductNumber = @ProductNumber
SET @lColor = @Color
SET @lStandardCost = @StandardCost
SET @lListPrice = @ListPrice
SET @lSize = @Size
SET @lWeight = @Weight
SET @lProductCategoryID = @ProductCategoryID
SET @lProductModelID = @ProductModelID
SET @lSellStartDate = @SellStartDate
SET @lSellEndDate = @SellEndDate
SET @lDiscontinuedDate = @DiscontinuedDate
SET @lThumbNailPhoto = @ThumbNailPhoto
SET @lThumbnailPhotoFileName = @ThumbnailPhotoFileName
SET @lrowguid = @rowguid
SET @lModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate

SET @lPageNbr = @PageNo
SET @lPageSize = @PageSize
SET @lSortCol = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SortColumn))

SET @lFirstRec = ( @lPageNbr - 1 ) * @lPageSize
SET @lLastRec = ( @lPageNbr * @lPageSize + 1 )
SET @lTotalRows = @lFirstRec - @lLastRec + 1

SET @SortMultiplier = CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'ASC' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END

; WITH ResultsCTE
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductID') THEN [ProductID] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Name') THEN [Name] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductNumber') THEN [ProductNumber] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Color') THEN [Color] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'StandardCost') THEN [StandardCost] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ListPrice') THEN [ListPrice] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Size') THEN [Size] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'Weight') THEN [Weight] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductCategoryID') THEN [ProductCategoryID] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ProductModelID') THEN [ProductModelID] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellStartDate') THEN [SellStartDate] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'SellEndDate') THEN [SellEndDate] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'DiscontinuedDate') THEN [DiscontinuedDate] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbNailPhoto') THEN [ThumbNailPhoto] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ThumbnailPhotoFileName') THEN [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'rowguid') THEN [rowguid] END,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'ModifiedDate') THEN [ModifiedDate] END
) AS ROWNUM,
Count(*) over () AS TotalCount,
[ProductID],
[Name],
[ProductNumber],
[Color],
[StandardCost],
[ListPrice],
[Size],
[Weight],
[ProductCategoryID],
[ProductModelID],
[SellStartDate],
[SellEndDate],
[DiscontinuedDate],
[ThumbNailPhoto],
[ThumbnailPhotoFileName],
[rowguid],
[ModifiedDate]
FROM SalesLT.Product
WHERE
(@lProductID IS NULL OR [ProductID] = @lProductID)
AND
(@lName IS NULL OR [Name] like '%' + @lName + '%')
AND
(@lProductNumber IS NULL OR [ProductNumber] like '%' + @lProductNumber + '%')
AND
(@lColor IS NULL OR [Color] like '%' + @lColor + '%')
AND
(@lStandardCost IS NULL OR [StandardCost] = @lStandardCost)
AND
(@lListPrice IS NULL OR [ListPrice] = @lListPrice)
AND
(@lSize IS NULL OR [Size] like '%' + @lSize + '%')
AND
(@lWeight IS NULL OR [Weight] = @lWeight)
AND
(@lProductCategoryID IS NULL OR [ProductCategoryID] = @lProductCategoryID)
AND
(@lProductModelID IS NULL OR [ProductModelID] = @lProductModelID)
AND
(@lSellStartDate IS NULL OR [SellStartDate] = @lSellStartDate)
AND
(@lSellEndDate IS NULL OR [SellEndDate] = @lSellEndDate)
AND
(@lDiscontinuedDate IS NULL OR [DiscontinuedDate] = @lDiscontinuedDate)
AND
(@lThumbNailPhoto IS NULL OR [ThumbNailPhoto] = @lThumbNailPhoto)
AND
(@lThumbnailPhotoFileName IS NULL OR [ThumbnailPhotoFileName] like '%' + @lThumbnailPhotoFileName + '%')
AND
(@lrowguid IS NULL OR [rowguid] = @lrowguid)
AND
(@lModifiedDate IS NULL OR [ModifiedDate] = @lModifiedDate)
)

SELECT * INTO #Results FROM ResultsCTE

SELECT @TotalCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM SalesLT.Product)

SELECT
[ProductID],
[Name],
[ProductNumber],
[Color],
[StandardCost],
[ListPrice],
[Size],
[Weight],
[ProductCategoryID],
[ProductModelID],
[SellStartDate],
[SellEndDate],
[DiscontinuedDate],
[ThumbNailPhoto],
[ThumbnailPhotoFileName],
[rowguid],
[ModifiedDate]
FROM #Results AS Results
WHERE ROWNUM > @lFirstRec AND ROWNUM < @lLastRec
ORDER BY ROWNUM * @SortMultiplier

RETURN @TotalCount

END
GO
```